# Transferring byte[] over sockets

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have a byte array that has to be sent to the server.

```
byte[] b=new byte[]{(byte)0xFE,0x01,0x01,0x32,0x00,0x00,(byte)0xFD};
```

My client code for sending is

```
PrintStream pw=new PrintStream(s.getOuputStream());
pw.Println(b);
```

My server code for receiving is

```
InputStreamReader in=new InputStreamreader();
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(in);
String s=br.readline();
System.out.println("client sent :" + s);
```

when server receives and prints the output i am getting the output as 
`client sent:[B@1f4917a7`

I want the output same as what is sent: `FE 01 01 32 00 00 FD`

Answer (score 1):

I few points you should know.

- don't send binary as text.  It is not text and sending binary this way is only likely to get it mangled.
- the `byte[].toString()` is brain dead.  Don't use it, it will only confuse you.  Instead you want `Arrays.toString(bytes)` if you want to print it.

I suggest you try

```
DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(s.getOuputStream());
out.writeInt(b.length);
out.write(b);
```

on the reading side

```
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
int len = in.readInt();
byte[] bytes = new byte[len];
in.readFully(bytes);
System.out.println("Client sent: " + Arrays.toString(bytes));
```

This should print

```
Client sent: [ -2, 1, 1, 50, 0, 0, -3 ]
```

This is the same data, as signed `byte` values in decimal.  You can format it to taste.

Comment: becoz sending part is one program and receiving part is in other program.

Comment: How to convert the output to FE 01 01 32 00 00 FD

Answer (score 0):

If you're sending byte arrays you're sending binary. So there is no reason to use a `Writer,` and many reasons not to.

Use `OutputStream.write(byte[])` or `OutputStream.write(byte[],int,int).`